# Как использовать семантику перемещения с initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move, семантика

```
struct MyString{
    string data;

    MyString(string&& str)
    : data(std::move(str)) {
    }

    MyString(const MyString&) = delete;
    MyString& operator=(const MyString&) = delete;

    MyString(MyString&& other) noexcept
    : data(std::move(other.data)) {
    }

    MyString& operator=(MyString&& rhs) noexcept {
        data = std::move(rhs.data);
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<MyString>({{"One"s}, {"Two"s}, {"Three"s}, {"For"s}});
}
```

Как использовать семантику перемещения при построении вектора, если его аргументом указан initializer_list?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал маленькую библиотеку специально для этого: [better_braces](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces)

Усложняем задачу: перемещающий конструктор и присвоение - долой, конструируем напрямую из строк.

<kbd>[запустить на gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:31,endLineNumber:23,positionColumn:31,positionLineNumber:23,selectionStartColumn:31,selectionStartLineNumber:23,startColumn:31,startLineNumber:23),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces/master/include/better_braces.hpp%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std::literals::string_literals%3B%0A%0Astruct+MyString%0A%7B%0A++++std::string+data%3B%0A%0A++++MyString(std::string+%26%26str)+:+data(std::move(str))+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++MyString(const+MyString%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++MyString%26+operator%3D(const+MyString%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3CMyString%3E+vec+%3D+init%7B%22One%22s,+%22Two%22s,+%22Three%22s,+%22For%22s%7D%3B%0A++++for+(const+auto+%26elem+:+vec)%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+elem.data+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-pedantic-errors+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wextra-semi+-Wdeprecated+-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header+-O3+-DNDEBUG%27,paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <better_braces.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

struct MyString
{
    std::string data;

    MyString(std::string &&str) : data(std::move(str)) {}

    MyString(const MyString&) = delete;
    MyString& operator=(const MyString&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyString> vec = init{"One"s, "Two"s, "Three"s, "For"s};
    for (const auto &elem : vec)
        std::cout << elem.data << '\n';
}
```